# What are web parts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-parts

What are web parts?

What are the benefits and drawbacks to using them?  Is there a difference between web parts in ASP MVC and Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx) are part of classic ASP.NET WebForms. They are special type of user controls. SharePoint being built with classic WebForms it uses Web Parts extensively to add functionality.

Web Parts are not used in ASP.NET MVC. Remember there's no ViewState nor Postback concepts in ASP.NET MVC. Similar functionality could be achieved with view models and partial views.

Comment: Any benefits or drawbacks that you know of to web parts?

Comment: Never used them so cannot comment. My first and last encounter with SharePoint was the moment I understood that I need to install and work with Visual Studio directly on the server. I think this was fixed in the latest version.